# Send Email with Credential Already Entered in Batch File

Tags: powershell, email, batch-file

I would like to send an email with powershell with credentials already entered using a batch file (not a powershell script).

I need this because it is a program where someone could request a feature, but it would use my email to send whatever they put in to myself. I don't want to have to give them my password.

I tried this, but it only works for the username, not the password:

```
powershell Send-MailMessage -To ansorensen1118@gmail.com -From ansorensen1118@gmail.com  -Subject Testing -Body Testing -Credential (new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username","password"))' -SmtpServer smtp.gmail.com -UseSsl
```

Comment: See: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: But if they run the batch file they must have your password.

Comment: No, my email password.

Comment: Solved!! I used the dynamic batch file. [Send a file to an email address using a bat file without exposing the email info?](https://superuser.com/questions/1366274/send-a-file-to-an-email-address-using-a-bat-file-without-exposing-the-email-info)

Comment: Close this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to provide the credentials like this:

```
$Username = 'username'
$Password = 'password'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$MySecureCreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass
Send-MailMessage ... -Credential $MySecureCreds
```

Comment: The question is clearly showing the [[tag:batch-file]] tag, and is using a [[tag:powershell]] command line, I'd assume entered within that [[tag:batch-file]]. What you've posted appears to be a [[tag:powershell]] script or a series of commands entered at the [[tag:powershell]] prompt. Could you please adapt your answer to better match the intent of the questioner?

Comment: @Compo, there is very little in the question to base any answer on. In other words, any attempt is a good intent.

Comment: Well @iRon, the edit clearly indicates that the little information I gleaned from the question as a base for an answer was assumed correct!